# Which is better way to put a link in a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, hyperlink

Well a quick question, I'm working with `button` elements and using them as `links`, I was wondering which is the best way to make `buttons` act like `links`.

1) wrapping it in `<a>` like:

`<a href="page.html><button> link </button></a>`

or

2) using `javascript` like:

```
<button onclick="location.href='page.html'">button</button>
```

Which is better way to use and why?

---

I'm much aware of that *how to ask questions* so instead of down voting and flagging it to close, an answer would be a lot better choice, so it might help me and those as well who do not know much that when do we use buttons and when do we not.

Comment: `<a href="page.html>link</a>` will suffice, why do you need `<button>`?

Comment: Don't use buttons as links (or even inside them). Use buttons as buttons and links as links. Style them to your liking.

Comment: My suggestion is use HYPERLINK and apply some CSS to make that look like BUTTON on UI. I am sure via Bootstrap CSS http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons you can achieve it. <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Link</a>

Comment: #1 isn't valid HTML anyway

Comment: @Satpal for a nav bar, i'm afraid i'm outta other options but buttons,

Comment: @Bergi what are the drawbacks in using `buttons` as `links`?

Comment: @RupeshKumarTiwari i'm not using `bootstrap`

Comment: You cannot be out of options. `button` and `a` are only different names for elements, but they have different native implementations.

Comment: Hassan, HTML is all about semantics. If you have a hyperlink reference (a link), you are supposed to use `a` (an anchor) that is supposed to do exactly that. Of course you can use three nested `div` and a `span` that you then give the functionality of a link, but why? Plus, people who have no JavaScript or have it deactivated will not be able to navigate your website.

Comment: Because it's twice the work for no reason. Choose the HTML elements based on the semantics they provide. A button is not necessarily a link and is not needed to create the clickability you want. And, a link doesn't natively do what a button does.

Comment: So you are telling us you can wrap your `button` in an `a` or add an `onclick` attribute to them, but you can not simply use `a` *instead* of `button`? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @domdom well that explains, I did forget the part that there are people who most probably like to disable `javascript` on their machines, so using it to make buttons act like links isn't a good way.

Comment: So if those two really are your only options then you need to decide between using non-validating HTML (because `button` is not valid content for `a`) or screwing over everyone who surfs without JavaScript (and maybe screen readers and other clients that depend on semantics?).

Comment: i see, so neither of em is a good option or even near to be good. :/

Comment: and what exactly there are `buttons` ever required for then? as @ScottMarcus said  _a link doesn't natively do what a button does._ what exactly a button does then? or why do we ever need to use em except for submitting a form

Comment: A button is a graphical element that supports a click event (among others) that can trigger **custom** user-defined operations. Since a hyperlink already performs navigation, the button doesn't apply.

Comment: To be clear, buttons come in different "flavors": button, submit, reset. submit is for submitting forms, button is for triggering custom operations that don't have a native element to trigger them. Imagine you had a mortgage calculator on a web page.... A button would be a good fit to trigger the calculation after all the data had been inputted.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanx mate, this explained a lot, :) , i've removed buttons from my code, and now just using `<a>` withc `class="button"` and applied `css` to make em look like buttons

Comment: That's the way to go. Good luck!

Comment: So you *were* able to alter the markup after all. You might as well accept Knitesh's answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an element the way it suppose to be used, you can apply styling if its a designer requirement.
For your problem if you using bootstrap, you can easily write:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="">Link</a>
```

Comment: While I agree that OP should just use an `a` tag, I'm wondering why a bootstrap-specific answer when there isn't even a bootstrap tag or mention in the question?

Comment: just an example, that a class can be applied to your tag

Comment: that's not what i asked @Knitesh, i could have used bootstrap but that's not what i was looking for, anyways

Comment: ok @HassanZia to answer your specifc questions, none of the way you mentioned is better than other

Comment: thnx anyways knitesh